# Split large datafile into multiple file with complete rows

Tags: c#

I want to split large data file (5 GB) into multiple files (5 files of 1 GB).

I am using this code:-

```
string destFileLocation = @"C:\Users\";
int index = 0;
long maxFileSize = 1073741824;
byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
//int a = buffer.Length;

using (Stream source = File.OpenRead(sourceFileName))
{
    try
    {
        while (source.Position < source.Length)
        {
            index++;
            // Create a new sub File, and read into t
            string newFileName = Path.Combine(destFileLocation, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sourceFileName));
            //destinationFile = new StreamWriter(
            //        string.Format(destinationFileName, fileCounter + 1));
            newFileName += "_" + index.ToString() + Path.GetExtension(sourceFileName);

            using (Stream destination = File.OpenWrite(newFileName))
            {
                try
                {
                    while (destination.Position < maxFileSize)
                    {
                         int bytes = source.Read(buffer, 0, (int)Math.Min(maxFileSize, buffer.Length));
                         destination.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);

                         if (bytes < Math.Min(maxFileSize, buffer.Length))
                         {
                             break;
                         }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    destination.Dispose();
                    destination.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        source.Dispose();
        source.Close();
    }
}
```

Now files are splitting between the rows but we need full rows.

Please provide some suggestion.

Comment: Please describe how your data is described in the files and what do u mean by a row?? If you mean a line then if you check for a new line character would that do the trick?

Comment: When you're looping through the bytes, look for newline characters.  When you reach your byte count for the file, either back-track to the last newline (by buffering "rows" and not flushing that buffer to the destination file and holding it for the next destination file) or continue writing until the next newline to finish the current "row" in the destination file.

Comment: like as we have data as below :- a b c d e f .... now when we are spliting then data are spliting between  the data like 1 row a b c and in next row d e f